# Mockito.verify with KafkaProducer and ProducerRecord

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mockito

I'm unit testing a very simple wrapper class for a KafkaProducer whose send method is simply like this

```
public class EntityProducer { 
    private final KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer;
    private final String topic;

    EntityProducer(KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer, String topic)
    {
        this.kafkaProducer = kafkaProducer;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void send(String id, BusinessEntity entity) throws Exception
    {
        ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
            this.topic,
            Transformer.HexStringToByteArray(id),
            entity.serialize()
        );
        kafkaProducer.send(record);
        kafkaProducer.flush();
    }
}
```

The unit test reads as follows:

```
@Test public void send() throws Exception
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> mockKafkaProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);
    String topic = "mock topic";
    EntityProducer producer = new EntityProducer(mockKafkaProducer, topic);

    BusinessEntitiy mockedEntity = Mockito.mock(BusinessEntity.class);
    byte[] serialized = new byte[]{1,2,3};
    when(mockedCipMsg.serialize()).thenReturn(serialized);

    String id = "B441B675-294E-4C25-A4B1-122CD3A60DD2";
    producer.send(id, mockedEntity);

    verify(mockKafkaProducer).send(
        new ProducerRecord<>(
            topic,
            Transformer.HexStringToByteArray(id),
            mockedEntity.serialize()
        )
    );

    verify(mockKafkaProducer).flush();
```

The first verify method fails, hence the test failis, with the following message:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
kafkaProducer.send(
    ProducerRecord(topic=mock topic, partition=null, key=[B@181e731e, value=[B@35645047, timestamp=null)
);
-> at xxx.EntityProducerTest.send(EntityProducerTest.java:33)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
kafkaProducer.send(
    ProducerRecord(topic=mock topic, partition=null, key=[B@6f44a157, value=[B@35645047, timestamp=null)
);
```

What is most relevant is that the key of the ProducerRecord is not the same, the value appears the same

Is the unit test properly oriented? How may I make the test pass?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to capture the argument and verify it. Please see the code below:

```
    ArgumentCaptor<ProducerRecord> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ProducerRecord.class);

    verify(mockKafkaProducer).send(captor.capture());

    ProducerRecord actualRecord = captor.getValue();
    assertThat(actualRecord.topic()).isEqualTo("mock topic");
    assertThat(actualRecord.key()).isEqualTo("...");
    ...
```

This is more readable (my view) and it is kind of document to what is happening in the method

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using Junit4.10 where assertThat(T).someMethod() does not seem to be available.

Comment: Thats from assertj (more readable way). http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html

Comment: The test works perfectly, how may I know in the future whether I should capture the argument or simply verify? It is because the instance of the `ProducerRecord` is created in the send method? Is it because of the implmementation of the `equals` method of the `ProducerRecord`?

Comment: Best use case could be because of `equal` method. Personally, I use tests as documentation for code. So, will use when I makes more readable

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
verify(mockKafkaProducer).send(
        new ProducerRecord<>(
            topic,
            Transformer.HexStringToByteArray(id),
            mockedEntity.serialize()
        )
    );
```

Means:
"Verify that '*send*' was called on '*mockKafkaProducer*' with the following arguments: ..."

This assertion fails, since send was actually called with different arguments.

Comment: I'm failing to see how the call in `verify` is with different arguments, where different means not `equals`, not meaning `!=` different, which is patent that is the case because a new object is instantiated every call, but the arguments to the constructor are the same

Comment: Decompiling `ProducerRecord` reveals that it does override `equals()`, but the statement 'the arguments to the constructor are the same' might not be true with regards to equals(), depending on the type that `Transformer.HexStringToByteArray()` returns. If that type (is it an actual byte array?) doesn't override equals(), this may explain the difference, since ProducerRecord's equals() compares the keys using `this.key.equals(that.key)`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That static does actually return a byte[], that may explain that the instances (of producer record) are not taken to be equal ...